# Is it possible to drop the items directly on the surface using librarycontainer

Tags: pixelsense

I am new to Microsoft surface, trying few examples using sdk 2.0. I have an example using LibraryContainer control, where I can drag and drop the items from source() to target control().

Here I want to achieve something different like instead of dropping the items on StackView, I want to drop the items directly on the surface from the Barview.

Kindly help me how to achieve this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a ScatterView control as the drop target

Comment: No, I want to drop it directly on the grid

Comment: @user that's unlikely.  Describe what you want to have happen from the users perspective.